# Combine two Column into One column with out union

Tags: sql-server

I have an Employee Table having two column city1,city2.

I want to select combine city1,city2 into single column with out using union.

Any other option for this?

Comment: Just concat them together? `SELECT CONCAT(city1, ' ', city2) as city FROM ...`

Comment: `UNION` is for appending rows to the final output, not columns.

Comment: Don't know why UNION is an issue, but you're the boss. ;) But can values of `city1` and/or `city2` be NULL? Do you want to include NULLs in the result? Do you want to get all values or only unique values?

Answer (score 2):

Join the two strings together. You can use [`CONCAT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to achieve this. In this example, we add a whitespace between the two, this can be changed to your needs.

```sql
SELECT CONCAT(city1, ' ', city2) as city 
FROM myTable
```

Alternatively you can use `+` to join strings together, although I recommend `CONCAT()` (in case any of them are null).

```sql
SELECT city1 + ' ' + city2 as city
FROM myTable
```

Answer (score 1):

If we assume that the OP does mean that want the results in the same way as a `UNION` (which I doubt), then you could use a `VALUES` expression:

```
SELECT V.City
FROM YourTable YT
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(YT.City1),(YT.City2)) V(City);
--WHERE V.City IS NOT NULL; --?
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`CONCAT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), you can combine the two column values into one column as

```
SELECT CONCAT(city1, city2) AS City
FROM Employee
```

In case if you want to add space in between column values, use `CONCAT(city1, ' ', city2)`